# Using Linker Symbol from C++ code as a fixed constant (NOT relocated) in a shared library (DLL)

Tags: gcc, dll, mingw-w64, relocation

Sorry if the title is not very clear. I am using MinGW with GCC 6.3.0 to build a x86 32-bit DLL on Windows (so far). I'll spare you the details why I need hacky offsets amongst its sections accessible from code, so please do not ask if it's useful or not (because I don't want to bother explaining *that*).

So, if I can get the following testcase to work, I'm good. Here's my problem:

In a C++ file, I want to access *a linker symbol as an absolute **numeric** value, **not** relocated*, directly. Remember that I am building a 32-bit DLL which requires a **.reloc** section for relocations, but in this case I do NOT want relocation, in fact a relocation would screw it up completely.

Here's an example: retrieve the *offset* of say `__imp__MessageBoxW@16` relative to `__IAT_start__`, in case you don't know what they are, `__imp__MessageBoxW@16` is the relocated pointer to the actual function at runtime, and `__IAT_start__` is a linker symbol in the default script file. Here's where it is defined:

```
.idata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
{
    /* This cannot currently be handled with grouped sections.
    See pe.em:sort_sections.  */
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$2))
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$3))
    /* These zeroes mark the end of the import list.  */
    LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0);
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$4))
    __IAT_start__ = .;
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$5))
    __IAT_end__ = .;
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$6))
    KEEP (SORT(*)(.idata$7))
}
```

So far, no problem. Because GAS doesn't allow me to "subtract" two externally defined symbols (both symbols are defined in the linker), I have to define the symbol in the linker script, so at the **end** of the linker script I have this:

```
test_symbol = ABSOLUTE("__imp__MessageBoxW@16" - __IAT_start__);
```

Then in C++ I use this little inline asm to retrieve this *relative difference* which is supposed to be *a fixed value* once linked:

```
asm("movl $test_symbol, %0":"=r"(var));
```

Now `var` should contain that *fixed number* right? Wrong!

Because `test_symbol` is an "undefined" symbol as far as the assembler is concerned, it makes it relocated. Or I don't know why, but I tried *so many things* to force it to be an "absolute constant value symbol" instead of a "relocated symbol" to no avail. Even editing the linker script with many things like `LD_FEATURE("SANE_EXPR")` and others, doesn't work at all.

Its value is correct *only if the DLL does not get relocated*.

You see, either GNU LD or the assembler adds an entry in the **.reloc** section for *that movl instruction*, which is WRONG!

Is there a way to force it to treat an external/undefined symbol as a fixed CONSTANT and apply **no relocation to it** whatsoever? Basically, omit it from the **.reloc** section.

I am going crazy with this, please tell me there's something easy I overlooked, I searched for *hours*!

In other words, is there a way to use a Linker Symbol from within inline asm/C++ *without* having it relocated whatsoever? No entry to the .reloc section or anything, basically same as a constant like $1234. So if a DLL gets loaded into another base address, *that constant would be the same* everytime.

**UPDATE:** I forgot about this question but decided to bring an update, since it seems it's likely not possible as nobody even commented. For anyone else in the same boat as me, I presume this is a *limitation of the COFF object format itself*. In other words, external symbols are implicitly relocated, and it doesn't seem there's a way against this.

I didn't "fix" it the way I wanted, I did it in a very hacky way though. If anyone is interested, here's my ugly "hack":

First I put a special "custom" instruction in the inline assembly where I reference this external symbol from C++. This "custom" instruction holds a placeholder instruction that grabs the symbol (normal x86 asm instruction with a dummy constant, e.g. 1234) and a way to identify it. Then let GCC generate the assembly files (.S files), then I parse the assembly with a simple script and when I find that "custom" instruction I insert a label for the linker (make it .global) and at the same time add a directive to a custom "on-the-fly" generated linker script that gets included from my main linker script at the end.

This places data in a temporary section in the resulting DLL with absolute offsets to the custom instruction that I need, but without relocation.

Next, I parse the binary DLL itself, in particular that temporary section I added with all this hack. I take the offsets from there, convert them to file offsets, and modify the DLL's .text section directly where those offsets point (remember those placeholder instructions? it is replacing their immediate constants 1234 with the respective value from the linker's non-relocated constant). Then I strip the temporary section from the DLL, and it's done. *Of course, all of this is done automatically by a helper program and script*

It's an insane hack, but it works and it's fully automatic now that I got it going. If my assumption is correct that COFF doesn't support non-relocated external symbols, then it's really **the only way** to use linker constants from C++ without them being relocated, which would be a disaster.